# How to change the color of the floating combat text in World of Warcraft Retail with lua

Tags: lua, interface, user-experience, world-of-warcraft

I just started programming my own addon for WoW to modify the interface. Now I would like to change the color of the floating combat text from yellow to all white.

I reviewed the add-ons "[NameplateSCT](https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/nameplate-scrolling-combat-text/files)" and "[MikScrollingBattleText](https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/mik-scrolling-battle-text)", but as I understand they create their own text frame and do not change the actual floating combat text of the game.

Is it possible to do it with simple lua code in one file? I want my addon to be the least cluttered and only provide the functionality to make it efficient. Here might be a relevant lua [repository](https://github.com/Gethe/wow-ui-source/blob/live/Interface/FrameXML/CombatFeedback.lua) for the wow interface.

I'm quite new to lua programming, so I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. My best guess is going with something like:

CombatFeedback_OnCombatEvent = function(self, event, flags, amount, type)
r = 1.0; g = 1.0; b = 1.0;
end

Comment: adding links to the mentioned addons and the WoW Lua API reference would increase the chances of getting an answer. also did you try anything yourself? can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

In the default UI there is "scrolling combat text" for self and "floating combat text" on units in the 3D world.

There are a few CVars that can modify the behavior for the 3D world text like [floatingCombatText*](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Console_variables#:%7E:text=floatingCombatTextAllSpellMechanics) and [worldText*](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Console_variables#:%7E:text=WorldTextCritScreenY) but changing font color does not seem to be available.